# How to generate such a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Saying that I have a table as below:

```
year    month    price
1991      1       1.1
1991      2       1.2
1991      3       1.3
1992      1       2.1
1992      2       2.2
1992      3       2.3
```

Now I want to generate such a table according to the table above:

```
year    m1    m2    m3
1991    1.1   1.2   1.3
1992    2.1   2.2   2.3
```

How to do this with SQL?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   Sorry, it's MySQL

Comment: I wouldn't. Instead I'd handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: I have been warned not to answer any more pivot query MySQL questions.  If you spend just a few minutes Googling or searching SO you will find tons of examples for how to do this..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thanks man, pivot query, never heard this before... lol

Comment: @Yves If you really get stuck somewhere, then come back and edit your question.  My guess, given your rep level, is that you won't get stuck :-)